# Is there an option to do a bulk/automated data backfill in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using "super metrics for big query" for pulling my account(s) performance which would use, super metrics for the data fetch and google big query for storing the data. 
The challenge is that, I would have to do a data backfill for the last 3 years for 100+ accounts. Is there a way to automate the process for all the accounts? Or can we send a backfill request for 180days/6months for multiple accounts simultaneously?

Note: BigQuery supports a maximum of 180 days per backfill request.

Comment: According to the documentation, you can not backfill data for multiple accounts, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#backfilling). Also, regarding the max backfill request , you can perform one request at a time, [link](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000098752-how-to-schedule-a-backfill-data-transfer-for-bigquery). In addition, the documentation does not mention any API automation for multiple accounts, I am still digging into it to check if it is indeed not supported.

Comment: Continuing, there is a tutorial how to perform a Data Transfer to BigQuery selection multiple accounts, here is the [link](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000098531-how-to-configure-a-data-transfer-in-bigquery). Would that help you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a BigQuery problem. You need to talk to Supermetrics to ask them for this service.

Comment: I can't mark as duplicate - please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374910/how-to-do-a-data-backfill-in-big-query